# QuantLib bindings for Octave?

Tags: c++, octave, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I want to use QuantLib from Octave.

From the QuantLib site:

> QuantLib is written in C++ with a clean object model, and is then
>   exported to different languages such as C#, Objective Caml, Java,
>   Perl, Python, GNU R, Ruby, and Scheme. The QuantLibAddin/QuantLibXL
>   project uses ObjectHandler to export an object-oriented QuantLib
>   interface to a variety of end-user platforms including Microsoft Excel
>   and OpenOffice.org Calc. Bindings to other languages and porting to
>   Gnumeric, Matlab/Octave, S-PLUS/R, Mathematica, COM/CORBA/SOAP
>   architectures, FpML, are under consideration.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation or examples that demonstrate how to do this?

Is there an Octave binding for Quantlib, and can someone provide either a snippet that shows how to use QuantLib from within Octave (or a link to such a snippet)?

I am thinking of writing SWIG wrappers around QuantLib for this purpose if nothing can be found - but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, if this has already been done ...

Comment: Actually, I have just noticed that the key sentence in the paragraph on the QuantLib site is: ` Bindings to other languages and porting to Gnumeric, Matlab/Octave, are **under consideration**.` It would appear that the Octave bindings are not available yet. So unless I am informed otherwise, I may have to start rolling my own SWIG bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have read the whole paragraph:

> Bindings to other languages and porting to Gnumeric, Matlab/Octave, S-PLUS/R, Mathematica, COM/CORBA/SOAP architectures, FpML, **are under consideration**. See the [extensions](http://quantlib.org/extensions.shtml) page for details.

Comment: We must have written this at the same time :)  - (see my comment above). I will accept your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at what I did for [RQuantLib](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html) and use the fact that both Octave and QuantLib are implemented in C++ -- but you will have to build bridges for the different object models.

Comment: I am already using RQuantLib :). Thank you very much for your excellent work. It is very much appreciated!